# Theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to modify a theme in Wordpress, I'm using it in a local server, but when I modified the style page of the theme, I don't see the result in the page.
My question is if someone knows How to fix the problem or well, How to modify the theme, but with really changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no caching plugin like WP super cache or WP Rocket is enabled. Finally, make sure the style.css file is writeable by the server with permission like `chmod 755`.

If the above does not help, you can use a custom CSS plugin (https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) and add your CSS code using its interface (cleaner and less hassle for everyday users).